A question in Strauss PDE exercise 9.4.2
In chapter 9.4 of Strauss PDE, we try to find the solution of 3D Diffusion Equation. And there is a exercise which is closely relating to the proof, as following:
$$\lim_{t\to0} \iiint_{R^3} S_3(X-X',t)\phi(X')~dX'=\phi(X)\tag{6}$$

Prove that (6) is valid for products of the form $\phi(X)=φ(x)ψ(y)ζ(z)$ and hence for any finite sum of such products
Deduce (6) for any bounded continuous function $\phi(X)$. You may use the fact that there is a sequence of finite sums of products as in previous part which converges uniformly to $\phi(X)$.

I had finished part 1. But in part 2, I am very confused about it. Why the Author said that "there is a sequence of finite sums of products as in previous part which converges uniformly to $\phi(X)$" ???
Thanks a lot!

He wants you to approximate $\phi$ by functions $\phi_j(X) = \varphi(x)\psi(y)\zeta(z)$, apply part 1, then take the limit as $j \to \infty$.

I means how to prove that the sequence of finite sums converge uniformly to the initial condition?

The existence of finite sums of products that converge uniformly to $\phi(X)$ is an analysis result. One way of proof is the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

But Stone-Weierstrass theorem only work for compact set, not the whole space. How does the theorem lead to the result?

Good point. There may be a way to salvage Strauss's proof. But you could just copy the 1-d proof, as it is essentially the same proof for higher dimensions.
